# Google Forms - Delete a single response

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I use a Google Form to capture membership details of an amateur organisation. When someone leaves, we mark them as LEFT on the form. However, under the new European GDPR legislation, we are required to physically delete details of any member who has left the group. In the latest version, you can delete a single entry by editing the Form and clicking on Responses ---> Individual ---> Delete but when there are a lot of entries, this is unspeakably tedious as you have to scroll through the entire response list to find the ones to be deleted. Is there a script function which will allow me to do this programmatically ?

Comment: Add google-form, google-apps-script tags